# get TileGroup to autoresize columns

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex-mobile

Not sure if I am doing this the best way but I want to create a mobile app that has a home menu screen much like the facebook iphone application(with out all the fancy button moves etc). The FB app has a 3X3 set of buttons that allow you to access things like news feed or friends.

In order to keep my layout consistent across different device screens I was trying to user the TileGroup with an image as a button for each tile.

but while I  can specify the tilegroup to use 100% width and height and set the number of rows and columns to 3. It does not appear to autosize the height of the rows and columns to fit the screen. and it won't let me specify the with/height as a percentage.

so my question is firstly am I doing the right thing or is there a better way to lay it out. And if I am doing the right thing, then how do I get the columns to auto size

Thanks in advance

JaChNo

Comment: `ColumnCount` is read only. Use `requestedColumnCount` instead. Same for the `rows`. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this. apply the following u may get what u needed

```
<s:TileGroup id="tile"
    columnCount="3"
    columnWidth="{tile.width / tile.columnCount}"
    rowCount="3"
    rowHeight="{tile.height / tile.rowCount}"
  />
```